# Creating a Table Backup Using SQL in Bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

How do I convert the below table backup query from Teradata to Bigquery,

```
CT [Db_Name].[Tablename1] AS [Db_Name].[Tablename] WITH DATA AND STATS;
```

Below code omits the partitions and clusters in Bigquery.

```
CT [Db_Name].[Tablename1] AS SELECT * FROM [Db_Name].[Tablename] ;
```

Everytime I try to take a backup, I have to create backup table DDL and Insert from Original to include partitions. Using Copy Utility is out of my scope in production. Is there any other way to achieve using SQL ?

Comment: but isn't ddl allowing you to define partitions and clusters? What is the problem?

Comment: I've found a way to do it today , I am basically Teradata developer so had a bit trouble converting to BigQuery first time. `CREATE TABLE [DB_NAME].[TABLE_NAME1]PARTITION BY (COLUMN_NAME) CLUSTER BY (COLUMN_NAME1) AS SELECT * FROM [DB_NAME].[TABLE_NAME] ; `